# git aws.push Error

Tags: git, amazon-web-services

I need to push my code on aws. For that I'm doing `aws.push`, but it throws an error sometime. But retrying it again 5-6 times, solves it. My question is why it didnt worked at first place, why I've to try 5-6 times. The error I get is

```
/mysite/.git/AWSDevTools/aws/dev_tools.rb:88: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 044077
fatal: unable to access 'https://AKIAJG6BWWPL7RPU52WA:20140323T144908Ze862da9a0e316156b474b5990633f5c827532e7fb4c9be1e5ae32c60cbd6a34e@git.elasticbeanstalk.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/6d7973697465/commitid/37313164336465666661396465303535666430376562656566393330623030303239326263373663/environment/6d79736974652d656e76/': Could not resolve host: git.elasticbeanstalk.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

Same is the case when I do `eb start` . Here is the error-

```
. HTTPSConnectionPool(host='elasticbeanstalk.us-east-1.amazonaws.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by <class 'socket.gaierror'>: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known)
```

**Why is it like that??**

Comment: I have the same issue now